# Adjust cordova screen width on xhdpi

Tags: cordova, viewport, device-width, pixel-ratio

I've a problem with a Cordova app I'm working on. I used a mdpi device for my tests and everything looks fine. I've got a width of 800 and a density value of 1. My view port is set like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
```

Now, I installed my app on another device, xhdpi. My problem is now the density value is 2 and with a screen width of 1200, my window.width is only 600, which mess up all the app, especially for the tables...

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the issue... Because 600px wide is really not enough...
As I get the pixel ratio via the screen global variable, I dynamically change the viewport meta tag attributes initial-scale and width with some calculated value. And now everything works fine!